# Merging two linked lists with no duplication

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, merge

I want to write a code to merge two linked lists such that the resulting list has **no duplication**. These two lists are ordered but may have duplication within them. The resulting list should be stored in the current list. The code should run in `O(n1+n2)` time where n1 is the size of the current list and n2 is the size of the other list.

This is a code that do merge two lists but **with duplication**. The running time of this code is `O(n1+n2)` and it stores the resulting list into the current list:

```
template <class T>
void DLList<T>::MergeInOrder(DLList<T>& otherList)
{
    if(otherList.IsEmpty() == true)
        return;
    if(IsEmpty() == true)
    {
        Append(otherList);
        return;
    }

    DLList<T> newList; 
    DLLNode<T> *thisPtr, *otherPtr;

    for(thisPtr = this->head, otherPtr = otherList.head;
        thisPtr != NULL || otherPtr != NULL; )
    {
        if(otherPtr == NULL)
        {
            newList.AddToTail(thisPtr->val);
            thisPtr = thisPtr->next;
        } 
        else if(thisPtr == NULL)
        {
            newList.AddToTail(otherPtr->val);
            otherPtr = otherPtr->next;
        }   
        else if(thisPtr->val <= otherPtr->val)
        {
            newList.AddToTail(thisPtr->val);
            thisPtr = thisPtr->next;
        }
        else
        {
            newList.AddToTail(otherPtr->val);
            otherPtr = otherPtr->next;
        }
    }
    Clear();
    Append(newList);
}
```

Any missing information?

Comment: Why not use set_union?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

Comment: This is the merging algorithm from merge sort. It however relies on assumption that lists contain no duplicates, so it won't work here. Consider two lists: `1 1` and `2 2`. This code will add both `1`s in a row, because they're both less than `2`.

Comment: Do you have any guarantees about the elements, specifically their order, in the lists? That is, if x comes after y in L1, then x' comes after y' in L2?

Comment: The two lists must be ordered descendingly. The code above works correctly but doesn't take care of duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will work since the lists are in descending order and the new list is also being built in descending order.

Before adding the next element to the new list, simply add a check:

```
if ( newNodeValue < lastAddedNodeValue )
  //only then add to list.
```

Comment: Amazing. This works but there is a problem that is when we add the first element to the newList then we can't check for the last added value because the tail would be NULL.

Comment: Another thing that the condition of if should be (newNodeValue > lastAddedNodeValue) because the newList should be sorted descendingly.

Comment: @ammarx for descending ordered lists new noee value should be less then last node value. Your 1st point can be fixed easily by properly initializing the lastnodevalue

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The list should be ascendingly ordered and the condition should be (newNodeValue > lastAddedNodeValue).
I can't initialize the newList while I don't know the range of list1 and list2 elements!.

Comment: So condition should be `if (newList.Empty() || newNodeValue != lastAddedNode->val)`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace each *incrementation of iterator* by a call to:

```
DLLNode<T>* nextDifferent(DLLNode<T> &node)
{
    const T& val = node.val;
    DLLNode<T> *res = node.next;

    while (res != nullptr && res->val == val) {
        res = res->next;
    }
    return res;
}
```

so `thisPtr = thisPtr->next;` become `thisPtr = nextDifferent(*thisPtr);`.

**EDIT**

Your loop should be something like:

```
for (thisPtr = this->head, otherPtr = otherList.head;
    thisPtr != NULL && otherPtr != NULL; )
{
    if (thisPtr->val < otherPtr->val)
    {
        newList.AddToTail(thisPtr->val);
        thisPtr = nextDifferent(*thisPtr);
    }
    else if (otherPtr->val < thisPtr->val)
    {
        newList.AddToTail(otherPtr->val);
        otherPtr = nextDifferent(*otherPtr);
    } else { // they are equal
        newList.AddToTail(otherPtr->val);
        otherPtr = nextDifferent(*otherPtr);
        thisPtr = nextDifferent(*thisPtr);
    }
}

while (otherPtr != NULL)
{
    newList.AddToTail(otherPtr->val);
    otherPtr = nextDifferent(*otherPtr);
}
while (thisPtr == NULL)
{
    newList.AddToTail(thisPtr->val);
    thisPtr = nextDifferent(*thisPtr);
}
```